# Correct form of lightswitch semaphore in C

Tags: python, c, semaphore

How should the correct alternative form of lightswitch semaphore look like in non-object oriented C language? Python reference of lightswitch semaphore is written in this paperwork [Little Book Of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf).

Lightswitch code:

```
class Lightswitch :

  def __init__(self):
    self.counter = 0
    self.mutex = Semaphore(1)

  def lock(self, semaphore):
    self.mutex.wait()
      self.counter += 1
      if self.counter == 1:
        semaphore.wait()
    self.mutex.signal()

  def unlock(self, semaphore):
    self.mutex.wait()
      self.counter -= 1
      if self.counter == 0:
        semaphore.signal()
    self.mutex.signal()
```

Comment: "_How should the correct alternative form of lightswitch semaphore look like in non-object oriented C language?_" is just a fancy way of saying "write code for me" which is not what this website is for.

Comment: @csm_dev There is no need to "write code for me". You could just point some ideas how should I do it. Nevermind, I made it anyways. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions could look like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int counter;
    sem_t mutex;

}LightSwitch;

void ls_lock(LightSwitch *ls, sem_t *sem){
    sem_wait(&ls->mutex);
    ls->counter++;
    if (ls->counter == 1)
    {
        sem_wait(sem);
    }
    sem_post(&ls->mutex);
}

void ls_unlock(LightSwitch *ls, sem_t* sem){
    sem_wait(&ls->mutex);
    ls->counter--;
    if (ls->counter == 0)
    {
         sem_post(sem);
    }
    sem_post(&ls->mut);
}
```